# quartz Fire Job immediately doesn't work

Tags: quartz-scheduler, spring-java-config

I integrated quartz 2 and spring 4 with maven and java annotation ( using servlet 3 ), also i am using tomcat 7 maven plugin for deploying my project,my quartz Configuration class like as below :

[image]

and my job class define simply like as below :

[image]

then i use the quartz Scheduler for using fire my job trigger immediately as below :

[image]

but my problem is  : when i call fireNow methode with "job1" , "mygroup"  parameters nothing happens and my job1 do not call immediately and don't print anything in console, i also track the db tables an i noticed 
after running the fireNow method new row inserted in my qrtz_triggers table in mysql:

[image]

Comment: Does fireNow gets executed at all. That is after some time. Have you taken into consideration that the DB I/O could be the cause for delay. Because The Scheduler properties is being read from DB transaction.

Comment: Were you able to load the quartz from database simply without any separate config as what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

If Quartz scheduler is not set to start automatically. You need to start it explicitly.

```
scheduler.start();
```

If Quartz scheduler started successful, you should see information in your log or console output similar as below.

[main] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.1)
'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' with instanceId 'MyScheduler'

Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.

NOT STARTED.

Currently in standby mode.

Number of jobs executed: 0

Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.

Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

...

[main] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - started

Comment: I used scheduler.start() before firing my job but nothing happens, I think i missed some configuration for integrating quartz and spring  with java config ,something like spring applicationContex am i right ? i thing spring does not aware of my quartz scheduler, also my cronTrigger config does not work at all

Comment: Just notice your cron "0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *", your job is supposed to be triggered on the first day of the month. If you want your job to be triggered every day, change it to "0 0/5 * * * ? *". In the log or console output, you should see Quartz start up information if Quartz started.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution for my problem, after enabling quartz log4j (adding log4j.logger.org.quartz=DEBUG in my log4j.properties ), I saw the jdbc exception in console, the exception related to using outdated quartz-query.

I added quartz 2.2.1 dependency in my POM but I used quartz sql query for 2.1.7 version and that mismatched between quartz jar and quartz sql query version cause missing some table like SCHED_TIME.